# How does one begin to find an asymptotic function of an infinite power series?

Tags: asymptotics

Say we have the infinite series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$
We want to attempt to find an asymptotic function/relation to the above series. How does one begin? I have never dealt with this area of math (undergraduate at the moment). Does one need the closed form of the infinite series in order to find the asymptotic behavior?

Comment: Asymptotic in what sense?  If you're interested in the case when $x \to 0$ then you can just truncate the series at any point.  If you're interested in the case when $x \to R^-$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series, then you may find something useful in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/726995/5531).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm pretty unfamiliar with this topic but I know for example you can find the asymptotic behavior of $n!$ (Stirling's Approximation). I want to approximate my infinite series. I want to see how fast it converges.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you're interested in seeing how fast the tail $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ tends to zero as $N$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Right, I have the closed form for my series. Is there any way using that or my series to find how fast? Some direction would be helpful. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: If you have a closed form for your series then you can probably take advantage of Taylor's theorem.  For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder